# PHP do While Loop issue

Tags: php, json, sql-server

Three queries execute at the same time and its declared one object $sql. In result "Product" Array Actually Four Record display only one Record,Three Record is not Display. In "total" Array Percentage Value Display null. Percentage is not declared filed in database.

I have need this Result :

```
 {"success":1,"product":[{"std_Name":"VIVEK SANAPARA","Standard":"12-SCI-CE","Division":"A","ExamDate":{"date":"2016-10-06 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"subject":"MATHS","ExamName":"WT","Marks":"30.00","TotalMarks":"30.00","PassingMarks":"10"},{"std_Name":"VIVEK SANAPARA","Standard":"12-SCI-CE","Division":"A","ExamDate":{"date":"2016-10-07 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Kolkata"},"subject":"PHYSICS","ExamName":"WT","Marks":"15.00","TotalMarks":"30.00","PassingMarks":"10"},{"std_Name":"VIVEK SANAPARA","Standard":"12-SCI-CE","Division":"A","ExamDate":{"date":"2016-10-08 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Kolkata"},"subject":"PHYSICS","ExamName":"WT","Marks":"25.00","TotalMarks":"30.00","PassingMarks":"10"},{"std_Name":"VIVEK SANAPARA","Standard":"12-SCI-CE","Division":"A","ExamDate":{"date":"2016-11-22 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Kolkata"},"subject":"PHYSICS","ExamName":"WT","Marks":"25.00","TotalMarks":"30.00","PassingMarks":"10"},],"total":[{"Marks":"30.00","TotalMarks":"30.00","Percentage":"79.166600"}],"exam":[{"ExamName":"WT"}]}
```

I have show Error Image below the Code. In image only one record display but in above result Four Record.Three Record is not Display in Image. Percentage Value Display null in image.

Marks.php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["insert"])) 
{ 
$reg = $_GET['reg'];

$sql = "select b.std_Name,d.Standard,e.Division,a.ExamDate,f.subject,a.ExamName,a.Marks,a.TotalMarks,a.PassingMarks 
                                  from Marks_mas a  inner join std_reg b on a.regno=b.regno 
                                  INNER JOIN Subject_mas as f ON a.Subject_ID = f.Subject_ID 
                                  inner join StandardMaster d on a.standard = d.STDID 
                                  inner join DivisionMaster e on a.Division = e.DivisionID 
                                  where a.RegNo= '$reg' order by a.ExamDate; select   sum(a.Marks) as Marks,sum(a.TotalMarks) as TotalMarks, sum(a.Marks)/sum(a.TotalMarks) * 100 as Percentage 
                                   from Marks_mas a 
                                   where a.RegNo= '$reg'; select distinct ExamName From Marks_mas;";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$result = array(); 

 if (!empty($stmt)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt) > 0) {

            $stmt = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

            $product = array();
            $product["std_Name"] = $stmt["std_Name"];
            $product["Standard"] = $stmt["Standard"];
            $product["Division"] = $stmt["Division"];
            $product["ExamDate"] = $stmt["ExamDate"];
            $product["subject"] = $stmt["subject"];
            $product["ExamName"] = $stmt["ExamName"];
            $product["Marks"] = $stmt["Marks"];
            $product["TotalMarks"] = $stmt["TotalMarks"];
            $product["PassingMarks"] = $stmt["PassingMarks"];

            $total = array();
            $total["Marks"] = $stmt["Marks"];
            $total["TotalMarks"] = $stmt["TotalMarks"];
            $total["Percentage"] = $stmt["Percentage"];

            $exam = array();
            $exam["ExamName"] = $stmt["ExamName"];


            // success
            $result["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $result["product"] = array();
            $result["total"] = array();
            $result["exam"] = array();


            array_push($result["product"],$product);
            array_push($result["total"],$total);
            array_push($result["exam"],$exam);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($result);


        } else {
            // no product found
            $result["success"] = 0;
            $result["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($result);

        }

        //sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
        sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnection first  

    }


}
```

Error In Image only one record display and above Actual result Four Record is Display. Error 2) Percentage value Display null.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygNH9.png)

Comment: Please, Give Me Any Solution

Comment: not clear, where you made the request and your insert statement?